# File size per video minute on iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, video, ios

What would be an average file size if recording 1 minute of video on the iPhone 6? Normal speed, no slow motion.

Comment: For 30fps or 60fps video?

Comment: Keep in mind that the answers below will vary because of file compression. Some scenes are more compressible than others. For example, a video with a constant background and small foreground subject is highly compressible because most of the picture stays constant between frames. A fast moving video shot on a roller coaster would have little similarity between frames, and would be less compressible (thus, larger).

Answer (score 3):

I checked now and it is 130 MB / minute.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, mark it as answered so that other people can see that it's answered :)

Comment: You cannot do that within 48 hours.

Comment: Sweet jesus that's high! I guess they aren't using lossy compression?

Answer (score 1):

60 FPS 10 minutes video 1.3 GB.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone6 22 minute video is 3.1GB. 3100/22 = 140MB per minute. 
This is 1920 x 1080 (1080p) @ 30 fps.

I checked the Frames Per Second in Settings>Photos & Camera>Record Video in my iPhone6 menu. I saw it was 1920x1080 pixels per frame when I imported the video to my Macbook using a program called Image Capture.